# ForEach && to check 2 Panels

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, foreach, panel

I am using For each to check labels within a panel. However, I want to check 2 panels. I can't figure out a way to have it check both panels. Below is what i tried and doesnt work.

```
foreach (Control x in panel1.Controls && panel2.Controls)
```

When i put the && it get the red line under. It works with one panel but when i add a 2nd it doesn't work. Any suggestions help would be great!

This code below works for one panel.

foreach (Control x in panel1.Controls)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `&&` is a built-in operator and returns a boolean value. If you want to iterate over the two control sets, you need to put them in one list, for example with the `union` extension method:

```
foreach(Control x in panel1.Controls.Cast<Control>().Union(
                     panel2.Controls.Cast<Control>()))
```

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Of course you're right. A cast should return an IEnumerable<>.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It worked out perfectly! Thanks for the learning lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loop does not allow binary operators in it. Read more about this [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `foreach`, and place `if` check in inner `foreach` loop.

Comment: No! Nested means you go over each inner item as often as you have outer items. The alternative would be two sequential loops.